What does dirty mean in Chrome's discards database?
I read in chrome://discards/database:

What does dirty mean?
I use Chrome on Windows 10.

In computer lingo, “dirty” means “modified”. So maybe these tabs (or rather, their contents) were modified after they were loaded?
